# Symbolic Link PowerPoint Slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is there a way to setup a series of PowerPoint presentations, say in the same folder, then setup one master powerpoint that when presented will import the slides in the folder to form one slideshow?

We, like many offices have slides that need to be updated by about a dozen people in the same hour, and I'm wondering if there isn't an easier way to just separate the slides out physically, then present them together logically without any manual overhead, since this isn't a very technically minded group.

I can't seem to find the right search terms for what I want to do, but I did try googling first :).

Comment: Are you looking for a programmatic solution to do this, like in VBA?

Comment: Well I was hoping I missed a checkbox that imports as a reference or something, but it didn't even occur to me to use VBA, I'm definitely going to look into what could be done there. Any hints in that direction would definitely help :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this programmatically, as in:

```
Sub InsertOtherDecks()
    Dim x As Presentation
    Set x = ActivePresentation
    x.Slides.InsertFromFile ("myslidedeck.pptx")
End Sub
```

You can also certainly do this via the client, but depending how much you need this and the control required [`Slides.InserFromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb265418(v=office.12).aspx) offers easier control over inserting from many different decks. But here's the manual version:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for